# In R, erase sections of string using data frame data

Tags: string, r, vectorization, substr, stringr

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
'data.frame':   81 obs. of  2 variables:
$ start: int  232 10697 10965 12279 15647 16897 17033 17612 17719 17983 ...
$ end  : int  243 10702 10970 12284 15652 16902 17038 17617 17724 17988 ...
```

I have a string that has content I want to erase at those start/end offset pairs. So, whatever is between byte offset 232 and 234, I want to "erase it" and collapse the space. I figured out that I want to process the string backwards, so that if I'm modifying it at the end, the offsets closer to the beginning are still valid. The code I have so far is:

```
for (i in nrow(cutpoints):1) {
   row = cutpoints[i,]
   substr(sc, row$start, row$end) <- " "
}
```

But when I print out sc afterwards, it's only removed the *first* character of every substring that I wanted removed. Does anyone have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? Furthermore, can this be vectorized?

**UPDATE** - I tried using stringr's str_sub:

```
> hw <- "Hadley Wickham"
> cuts <- data.frame(start=c(1,8), end=c(6,14))
> str_sub(hw, rev(cuts$start), rev(cuts$end)) <- " "
> hw
[1] "Hadley  "  "  Wickham"
```

So, clearly I don't understand what I'm doing with string processing in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to work with vectors of ranges to keep instead of ranges to cut. This is pretty easy to do by flipping the starts and ends and adjusting slightly:

```
hw <- "Hadley WickhamPLUSENDING"
cuts <- data.frame(start=c(1,8), end=c(6,14))
keeps <- data.frame(start=c(1, cuts$end+1), end=c(cuts$start-1, nchar(hw)))
keeps
#   start end
# 1     1   0
# 2     7   7
# 3    15  24
```

Substrings that start after they end will simply return no characters, so they are not an issue with our method.

You can use `apply` to vectorize the operation of keeping everything between each start/end pair:

```
pieces <- apply(keeps, 1, function(x) substr(hw, x[1], x[2]))
pieces
# [1] ""           " "          "PLUSENDING"
paste(pieces, collapse="")
# [1] " PLUSENDING"
```